# ¿Cómo hago una suma de valores en conjuntos de 3 de un arreglo en C++?

Tags: c++

Tengo una duda y no la puedo resolver, perdón si es tonta pero estoy aprendiendo solo, estoy creando un programa que sume los valores de un conjunto de 3 en 3 con arreglos, pero no se como sumar los valores del arreglo de 3 en 3, el programa tiene que funcionar así:

> 8 (numero de números del conjunto)
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 (números del conjunto que ingresa el usuario)
>
> 13 (número cualquiera que ingresa el usuario)

El programa tendría que sumar todos los valores en conjuntos de 3, así:

> 1+2+3= 6 por tanto es menor que 13
>
> 2+3+4=9 por tanto es menor que 13
>
> 3+4+5=12 por tanto es menor que 13
>
> 4+5+6=15 por tanto es mayor que 13
>
> 5+6+7=18 por tanto es mayor que 13
>
> 6+7+8=21 por tanto es mayor que 18

El programa me tiene que devolver cuantas sumas son mayores que el número que ingresa el usuario, por tanto en mi caso el programa tendría que regresarme que 3 pero no se como hacerlo, miren esto es lo que trato de hacer pero mi código no compila por que no se como ingresar la suma de los números que ingresa el usuario en conjuntos de 3 en 3:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int arreglo[100];
int Cuantos;
int NumeroAComprobar;
int suma;

int main()
{
    cin >> Cuantos;
    for(int i=1; i<= Cuantos; i++){
        cin >> arreglo[i]
    }
    cin suma;
    suma=
    cin>>NumeroAComprobar;
    int contador=0;
    for(int i=1; i<=Cuantos; i++)
    {
        if(suma>NumeroAComprobar){
            contador++;
        }
    }
    cout<<contador;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola, podrias decir si la respuesta dada te fue util

Comment: Todavía no logro hacer que el programa funcione pero aun así me diste una idea de como hacerlo, muchas gracias

Comment: Bueno cualquier duda que tengas me dices y por favor si la respuesta te fue util no olvides aceptarla o votarla, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int longitud = sizeof(arreglo) / sizeof(arreglo[0];
int suma = 0;
int cont = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < longitud - 3; i++)
{
   suma = arreglo[i] + arreglo[i + 1] + arreglo[i + 2];

   if(suma > numeroAcomprobar)
   {
      cont++;
   }
}

//imprimo la variable cont
```

Primero hallamos la longitud del arreglo, de esta forma ya no tenemos que preocuparnos de la cantidad de elementos que tiene el arreglo, después ejecutamos un **ciclo for** que irá desde la primera posición del arreglo hasta la antepenúltima, posteriormente guardamos en la **variable suma** la suma de los tres elementos consecutivos del arreglo y verificamos si esta suma es mayor al número introducido por el usuario, de serlo aumentamos en **1** a **cont**, por último cuando salimos del ciclo imprimimos el valor de **cont**.